# AS3 bug? Newline automatically entered after css tag

Tags: html, css, flash, actionscript-3, textfield

I am rendering a TextField (Flash CS5) with the following css and html properties :

```
css = "a {font-weight: bold;} fu {color: #00A0A0;}"
wordWrap = true
multiline = true
html = <![CDATA[&quot;Phoenicians were pioneering artisans and ingenious craftsmen…

They developed the technique behind the production of transparent glass…

Their innovation spread around the globe throughout the past centuries…

<fu>WE AIM TO CARRY ON WITH THE INNOVATION</fu>&quot;]]>
```

The last QUOTE is rendered in a line BELOW "WE AIM TO...". It's rendered like this :

...

WE AIM TO CARRY ON WITH THE INNOVATION

"

The ONLY way to render the quote in the same line with "WE AIM..." is to :

a) Either put it INSIDE `<fu>`

b) Or remove `<fu>` altogether.

Is this a Flash bug? Am I doing something wrong with css or html?

Many thanks in advance,

Bill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of going the complex "span" way, just add this in you css description:

css = "a {font-weight: bold;} fu {color: #00A0A0; ***display:inline;***}"

Comment: Thanks! this was driving me crazy

Comment: I know that feeling. I meet it every so often.

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that `htmlText` supports only a **[limited number of tags and attributes](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/TextField.html#htmlText)**, and thus CSS support is frankly quite poor. So it is not a bug, but a known limitation...

My recommendation would be to use a **span tag** with a **class attribute**, like:

```
css = ".foo {color: #00A0A0;}"

html = "&quot;[...]the past centuries…
<span class=\"foo\">WE AIM TO CARRY ON WITH THE INNOVATION</span>&quot;";
```